# How to send PDF blob from axios AJAX request as email attachment in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, axios, nodemailer

I have the following code which sends some html to my node.js API and converts it into a PDF. I then want to send that PDF as an attachment. The docs say working with streams / file paths etc is done via the `content` property of the attachment but I'm not sure how to process with my blob data.

I've tried the following but it results in a node error of `Invalid non-string/buffer chunk`. I can send the email with random text in `content` and it attaches a PDF but it's not readable.

How do I get my blob data and send it as a PDF attachment without first saving the file?

```
emailInvoice () {
    Axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://myApi/api/html-to-pdf',
      data: {
        html: this.getInvoiceHtml()
      },
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(function (pdfResponse) {
      Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/send-email', {
        host: '##',
        port: '26',
        user: '##',
        pass: '##',
        to: '##',
        from: '##',
        subject: 'Invoice ' + this.model.doc.ref,
        text: 'Test Text',
        html: '<b>TEST</b>',
        attachments: [{
          filename: this.model.doc.ref + '.pdf',
          content: pdfResponse.data,
          contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }]
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('Email Success')
        console.log(response)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Email Error')
        console.log(error)
      })
    }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('PDF Error')
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

**Edit** - I've tried removing the `responseType: 'blob'` so my data looks something like:

> %PDF-1.4↵1 0 obj↵<<↵/Title (��)↵/Creator (��)↵/Producer (��Qt
>   5.5.1)↵/CreationDate (D:20171030091844)↵>>↵endobj↵2 0 obj↵<<↵/T

and I'm managing to send a PDF of the right size now but it's blank.

**EDIT 2**

I've just added a new route to my node api and done this all server side and it has worked. Passing the stream data directly from `html-pdf` to `nodemailer` appears to work. I'd still be interested in how to send this data as a file attachment in nodemailer without saving the file first.